# wget: не хватает памяти

Tags: wget

Есть репозиторий статических файлов, доступный только по http. Файлы постоянно меняются. Пытаюсь создать зеркало. Запускаю скрипт:

```
wget \
--mirror -R "index.html*" \
--exclude-directories=$ExclDir \
-P /mnt/mirror/ \
--append-output=/var/log/wget.log \
http://10.3.128.249/
```

На первом же большом файле (3.7 Гб) wget падает и выдает "wget: не хватает памяти". Выяснил, что при копировании большого файла на 99% wget начинает отъедать оперативу (её 2 Гб), и отъев всю, что имеется, падает.
Как победить?

P.S.: Создал контейнер с такими же параметрами (2 Гб RAM, 50 Гб под корень), всё загружается без ошибок.

Comment: Интересно, wget 32-х битный? А сама операционная система?

Comment: `wget` не должен так делать — звучит как баг... если файл загружать одиночно, то он нормально грузится? и случаем не в tmpfs загружаешь? swap на тачке есть?

Comment: wget - x64, система - x64, одиночная загрузка файл загружает, гружу в ext4, swap 1 Гб.

Answer (score 0):

Для успешной загрузки больших файлов с помощью wget с параметром "--mirror" требуется swap объемом больше загружаемого файла. Проверено эмпирически.
Было дано:
Гипервизор Proxmox 5.1;
Виртуальная машина  (2 Гб RAM, 40 Гб под корень, от 2 до 10 Гб под swap);
Debian Stretch 9.8;
wget 1.18.
Для lxc без swap с теми же параметрами wget загружает файлы без ошибок.